# Software developers/engineers aged out?

Tags: discrimination

A number of colleagues, and myself, were shown the door from Wall Street firms at around age 55.

It has already been observed that the average age of a software developer according to Stack is about 33.

Rather than ruminate on the maybes and why's, can anyone confirm that this is policy?

A terrible waste of priceless experience and talent, it must be.

There isn't even an "age" or "ageism" or "age discrimination" tag here, which I take to be confirmation of the premise.

Comment: I cannot confirm, nor does it matches my observations. I have lot of colleagues and know other people who work as software developers age 55+, and getting hired at that age.
But I vote close to your question since it is more a rant, than question with a problem that can be addressed.

Comment: "can anyone confirm that this is policy"  It would be difficult to confirm this, and it would only be for that particular industry / perhaps country.  Anecdotally, in "my" software universe, ancient programmers are sought, because in general it is so hard to find anyone good. (indeed:  purely in my experience, young programmers are bitter that ancient idiots basically get preference!) Purely in "my" universe I have not seen what you say. Programmers are like legend rock guitarists.  Joe Walsh, Jimmy Page, etc crap on youngsters, they're cooler, do more drugs, still live harder, etc.!

Comment: The bold part in [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/172906/125897) may explain an impact how that average might have came about.

Comment: @Helena It is a valid question, and there are people who are in a position to answer it.  Not being in such a position on anyone's part does not render the question a "rant."

Comment: @Levente  Aye. There was a time when guitar players were in demand.  Now they grow on trees.

Comment: @Fattie Made my guitarist comment before reading yours...all I can say is save your moneys.  Lots of great players on the streets.

Comment: @blahdeBlah what is the question?

Comment: Old people literally run the world to force young people out. If you're having problems too, that's concerming.

Comment: In NYC it's illegal to make employment decisions based solely on the fact you are 40 or older. If a Wall St firm is regularly doing this then that sounds like an easy pattern to prove.

Comment: @blah deBlah, No one can confirm if there is an "unofficial policy" for aging out.  I think lots of software developers who are 55 or older are very sharp, talented, quick-thinking, capable, and have great industry experiences. Maybe, the layoffs happen because of the on-going pandemic and companies want to cut cost ?

Comment: Good software developers are like great wine. The older they get, the better they are. Cheers. :-)

Comment: @blahdeBlah I have just realized the semantics of your response, and I find I'm not happy with how you candidly toss back your interpretation of the fact that I shared with you, as if I suggested that interpretation. I did not suggest that interpretation.

Comment: This depends on the year. Every field has a time when there is tremendous demand for all talent and times when highly skilled talent is let go and can be found driving Lyft. The business cycle is brutal in that regard. When the fad was to fire expensive US talent and send all the work to India, there was a glut of experienced developers on the market. Right now, there is high demand. So, do not look at this as policy as much as business fads and cycles.

Comment: You hear this, yet I don't know any older programmers who had trouble getting jobs.  What I have seen is older programmers choosing to go into other fields, especially when they get to the point of needing to retrain in new technologies when they're burnt out.  I also know a lot of top engineers who go on to form their own startups or retire early after making serious money at a FAANG.  While I can't speak for specific subfields, I think this is more fud than reality.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the number of software developer jobs has grown has grown explosively over the last decade, and most of the new employees are fresh graduates, not necessary even from related field. To answer the point about ageism, you should find some numbers about the development of absolute numbers of jobs in different age brackets.